# Downloading file in Laravel 10 in browser

Tags: php, laravel, file, download

I'm creating files using Jasper and now what I want to do is when user presses the button he will start to download those files, but when I tried it the response code is 200 but the popup window for the downloading on the device doesn't happen. The files are saved in my folder in the app.

Here is that part of the code;

```
 public function generateReport(array $parameters, string $fileName, $request)
    {
        //Checking and getting formats from request
        $acceptedFormats = [
            'PDF', 'XLS', 'XLSX', 'DOCX', 'PPTX', 'CSV', 'HTML', 'RTF', 'TXT', 'XML',
            'ODT', 'ODS',
        ];

        $jsonBody = $request->getContent();
        $requestData = json_decode($jsonBody, true);
        $formats = $requestData['formats'] ?? [];

        foreach ($formats as $format) {
            if (!in_array(strtoupper($format), $acceptedFormats)) {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid format: ' . $format);
            }
        }

        //Fetching, preparing and creating files
        $jrxmlFile = __DIR__ . '\Reports\Template\\JasperFiles\\' . $fileName . '.jrxml';

        $jasper = new PHPJasper();
        $jasper->compile($jrxmlFile)->execute();

        $jasperFile = __DIR__ . '\Reports\Template\\JasperFiles\\' . $fileName . '.jasper';
        $outputFile = __DIR__ . '\Reports\Output\\' . $fileName;

        $jasperConfig = config('jasper.db_connection');
        $options = [
            'format' => $formats,
            'params' => $parameters,
            'db_connection' => $jasperConfig
        ];


        //Where the magic happens
        $jasper->process(
            $jasperFile,
            $outputFile,
            $options,
        )->execute();



        $filePath = $outputFile . '.pdf';
        $headers = [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
        ];
        return response()->download($filePath, $fileName, $headers);
    }
```

The file creation works but I can make it so the download starts, here is the api for the FE:

```
    export async function generateReportForOneProduct(
    id: number,
    body: { formats: string[] }
) {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(
            `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}/api/product/${id}/generateReport`,
            {
                formats: body.formats.map((format) => format.toLowerCase()),
            },
        );
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error inserting variant:", error);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

What can I try next?

Comment: I'd remove the unnecessary "Content-Type" header from the Axios POST request on the frontend first.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski did it, still the same

Comment: you can't download a file through an ajax request. If you must keep it an ajax request you must store the file in server, send the url to the file to the FE and have the FE redirect the user to the url in a new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue that might be occurring if you are doing this on Chrome is that the popups are disabled for multiple file downloading, so you will need to go to the settings to change that. The second thing from what I understood in your code is that you will get a list of the paths for these extensions and you can go through them and download them separately.

Here is an example:

```
const { filePaths } = response.data;

    for (let i = 0; i < filePaths.length; i++) {
        const filePath = filePaths[i];
        const url = `${
            process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL
        }/api/v1/download?filePath=${encodeURIComponent(filePath)}`;
        const isPopupsBlocked = window.open(url, "_blank");
        if (!isPopupsBlocked) {
            alert("Please enable pop-ups to download multiple files.");
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yup just tried it works, thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a link programmatically and trigger clicking on it. After that, you can remove the link (programmatically).

```
const fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]))

const link = document.createElement('a')
link.href = fileURL
link.setAttribute('download', `file_name.pdf`)
document.body.appendChild(link)
link.click()
link.remove()
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL)
```

Comment: Like mentioned above I already have a button with endpoint for downloading the files, it BE related